# Java program to compare two text files, then replace variables found in the first text file with those in the 2nd file into a 3rd file

Tags: java, file, file-io, text-files, file-manipulation

So I would like to ask if there is any way to modify the code I currently have in order to make it so it only replaces certain parts of the text file. 
Let's say I have a text file called TestFile1 that contains

> A = Apple
>   B = Banana
>   C = Carrot
>   D = Durian

And another called TestFile2 which contains

> A = Art
>   C = Clams

What I would like to happen is that the code should be able to compare the two text files and if it finds that there are two variables that match, the output file which would be TestFile3 would look like this

> A = Art
>   B = Banana
>   C = Clams
>   D = Durian

Also, I would like to make it dynamic so that I don't have to change the code every single time that the variables are changed so it can be used for other text files.

At the moment, I currently only have this code, but what it only does is that it just fully replaces TestFile2 with TestFile1 entirely, which is not what I intend to happen.

```java
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.OpenOption;
import java.nio.charset.Charset; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindAndReplaceTest {

    static void replaceTextFile(String fileName, String target, String replacement, String toFileName) throws IOException
    {
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        Path toPath = Paths.get(toFileName);
        Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(toPath, charset);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path, charset.name());
        String line;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            line = line.replaceAll(target, replacement);
            writer.write(line);
            writer.newLine();
        }
    scanner.close();
    writer.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        replaceTextFile("C:\\Users\\LS1-10\\Documents\\TestFile2.txt", "Write", "Read", "C:\\Users\\LS1-10\\Documents\\TestFile1.txt");
        /* 
        System.out.println("Note: Make sure files to merge are in the same directory as this program!");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String output, file1name, file2name;
        System.out.print("Enter output file name: ");
        output = in.nextLine();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(output + ".txt"); 

        System.out.print("Enter name of first file: ");
        file1name = in.nextLine();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1name + ".txt")); 
        String line = br.readLine(); 

        System.out.print("Enter name of second file: ");
        file2name = in.nextLine();
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2name + ".txt")); 

        line = br.readLine(); 

        pw.flush(); 

        br.close(); 
        pw.close(); 

        System.out.println("Replaced variables in " + file1name + ".txt with variables in " + file2name + ".txt into " + output + ".txt"); */
    }
}
```

I commented out the part of the psvm that would ask for user input on what the file names would be because I just took it from a previous program that I made so all I need is something that would compare the two files and make the output appear as intended. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way, given everything fits into memory would be to:

1. deserialize file2 to a map
2. upon reading file1, check if the variable has an associated value in the map, and replace if needed before outputing to file3.

Comment: How would that be done? I think I'm still very noob-ish when it comes to this. Thank you for answering!